# Can I respond to a menu item housed in a List Item via its click event?

Tags: javascript, meteor, html-lists, menuitem

To set a Session variable in response to the selection of a menu item, should a list item click event replace an anchor tag?

In my Meteor app, I originally intended to use iron router routing in response to menu item selections, like so:

```
<li><a href="{{pathFor route='scheduleOpenExisting'}}">Open Existing</a></li>
```

...but now am thinking I would rather use dynamic templates, and use the value of a Session variable to replace the Template in the body (SPA-style). So is this the way to go about that:

html:

```
<li name="mniOpenExisting" id="mniOpenExisting">Open Existing</li>
```

Javascript:

```
"click mniOpenExisting": function (event) {
    return 'openExistingTemplate';
    // In actuality, I will use:
    //Session.set('curTemplate', 'openExistingTemplate');
}
```

?

IOW, I can just do away with the anchor tag and respond to the click of the menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct, the `<a>` is not required.

```
"click #mniOpenExisting": function (event) {
  // take action here when element with id 'mniOpenExisting' is clicked
}
```

[I like the coding style set out here](http:///www.codementor.io/tips/7473712871/a-better-way-to-attach-event-listeners-in-meteor), with the separation between ids and classes used for presentation and the data- tags for event handlers.

Iron:router is still 'SPA-style', however the additional functionality it has already built in may save you time and keep your code cleaner that reimplementing this functionality yourself, though that depends on how complex your app will be.

Also see [Meteor UI Pattern: Keeping App State on the URL](https://meteorhacks.com/meteor-ui-pattern-keeping-app-state-in-the-url).  This is generally a much better option than having Session variables for the same task.